# Prisma mongodb removing entry by userId

Tags: mongodb, prisma

I'm trying to remove a category from my db by using one of it's props: userId but I'm getting the following error:

```
Type '{ userId: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CategoryWhereUniqueInput'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'userId' does not exist in type 'CategoryWhereUniqueInput'.ts(2322)
```

I understand this means the value isn't unique but then I'm confused how else I'm supposed to remove the item. Here's my schema for user and category:

```
model Category {
  id                String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  title             String
  userId            String @db.ObjectId

  user              User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade )
  reminders         Reminder[]
}

model User {
  id                String @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  email             String? @unique
  name              String?
  emailVerified     DateTime?
  hashedPassword    String?
  image             String?
  createdAt         DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt         DateTime @updatedAt
  deadlines         String[] @db.ObjectId

  accounts          Account[]
  reminders         Reminder[]
  expiredReminders  ExpiredReminders[]
  categories        Category[]
}
```

I don't want to make title unique because that'll prevent multiple users from having the same category titles and I don't want to bring the ID to the frontend because I'm assuming that's bad practice.

Any ideas?